# When I enter localhost/MyController/MyActionName/1 i get a null in the optional parameter why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

## SOLUTION

the route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      "Whatever", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", //{ID} MUST BE USED IN YOUR CONTROLLER AS THE PARAMETER 
      new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

#### And that's it! I guess you must use the name of the id in the 
public actionresult(int id //must be ID HERE like global.asax)

```
Steps to reproduce my problem: 
1. Create a new mvc3 application
2. Go to home controller and put Index(int? x){ return view()}
3. Run the application
4. Go to the url type in the url http://localthost:someport/Home/Index/1
5. Insert a break point in controller to see the value of x 
6. Notice that even if you put the url above x NOT equal to 1 as is suppose to!
```

I just dont understand why i am getting a null in the id....

```
 public ActionResult MyActionName(int? id)
    {
       //the id is null!!!!!!!!!!!! event thought i just entered the url below!
    }
```

I enter the following url in my browser 
http://locahost/MyController/MyActionName/1

//I also put this in my global.asax but it doesnt really help.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
      "Whatever", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

AND!
My error if I put

```
  public ActionResult MyActionName(int id)
        {
           //the id is null!!!!!!!!!!!! event thought i just entered the url below!
        }
```

Note that the above example was made for simplicity this error is for the actual application.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'MvrId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'MedicalVariance.Controllers.MedicineManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'MvrId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'MedicalVariance.Controllers.MedicineManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Is that the only route you have in your global.asax? Please show your entire RegisterRoutes and Application_Start methods. That might help.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to check that the id is null? Have you verified that the code within your action is, in fact, being executed at all?

Comment: -1.  The question is unclear.  The steps do not allow me to reproduce the error. I'm not sure what I am supposed to notice in Step 6.  Step 4 discusses the Home/Index url whilst the next url and route mentions MyController/MyActionName.  You have discussed other routes but when asked by members you have not provided them.  And you have provided an error message which seems irrelevant.

Comment: An additional -1 (if it was possible) for answering the question in the question (in an unclear manner and before the question that is asked) and not waiting to answer your own question.  I take back the part of my previous comment stating that the steps would not allow you to recreate the issue but as this question is a mixture of (int? x) and (int? id) you can understand my confusion.  This question is a mush of the original question, updates and the answer in no particular order and needs to be restructured for it to be of any use to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your route is defined before the default route.

Comment: I am still getting a null after i tried to put before default route. Also I dont want to localhost to go to MyController/MyActionName by default.

Comment: If it was after the default route, he wouldn't even be getting to the stage to check the id.

Comment: @jvelez the default route is always the catch-all route. If you don't put your route before the catch-all route it will never get there (because the catch-all route will swallow it up). As long as your url is not in the /controller/action format, it won't default to that don't worry.

Comment: @DarylTeo the catch all route would be able to route him to this simple controller/view route.